# JSON.stringify is ignoring data, returns {}

Tags: javascript, json, angular, typescript

I am new to javascript and facing an issue when convert objects using `JSON.stringify()`.

Below is the code:

```
const tmp4 = this.getrulecondition2(rule._id, key); //this returns the object that I need to convert to json string..

console.log(tmp4); //shows the output as below in the chrome console.
//{}Command: "ps"Match: "test"Name: "test"Regex: "test"Terminal: "test"__proto__: Object

var str = JSON.stringify(tmp4);
console.log(str); //shows {} in the console log.
```

I am wondering it is proceeding to convert the stringify statement before it gets the object from function return. How can I make sure it proceeds to the next line only after getting the function results?

Comment: The answer almost certainly depends on what `this.getrulecondition2()` does, but you did not post that.

Comment: The output from `console.log(tmp4);` - are you sure that's the exact output? it looks very wrong.

Comment: I suspect this is a asynchronous issue.  The object is empty, but the `console.log` doesn't execute until later, when the object has been populated.  Please add the code for `getrulecondition2` to the question.

Comment: the output from `console.log(tmp4);` doesn't look like valid json